# PDFKit: Unknown image format error for PNG

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I'm using the prebuilt version of [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) in the browser, and when attempting to add a PNG I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown image
    PDFImage.open                             format.util.js:546
    module.exports.image                      deflate.js:773
    img.onload                                PDFrenderer.js:195
```

I'm converting my images to PNG on the server (to crop them into circles) and the mime type of the images returned by the server is 'image/png'.  I'm unsure whether the method I'm using to convert the PNG into an ArrayBuffer is incorrect.

Here is the code I use to fetch the PNG and convert it  into an ArrayBuffer:

```
var img = new Image, ctxData;

img.onError = function () {
    throw new Error('Cannot load image: "' + url + '"');
}

img.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctxData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').slice('data:image/png;base64,'.length);
    ctxData = atob(ctxData);
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);

    var buffer = [];

    for (var i = 0, l = ctxData.length; i < l; i++) {
        buffer.push(ctxData.charCodeAt(i));
        buffer._isBuffer = true;
        buffer.readUInt16BE = function (offset, noAssert) {
            var len = this.length;
            if (offset >= len) return;

            var val = this[offset] << 8;
            if (offset + 1 < len)
                l |= this[offset + 1];
            return val;
        }
    }
    pdf.image(buffer);
}

img.src = url;
```

This works fine for JPEGs when this line is changed from

```
ctxData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').slice('data:image/png;base64,'.length);
```

to

```
ctxData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
```

however I need to be able to pass in PNGs so that I can place I can place round images over any background.

I've also tried passing in the full url (e.g. 'http://mysite.dev/userimages/1234/roundavatar.png'), however I'm then presented with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    PDFImage.open                 util.js:535
    module.exports.image          deflate.js:773
```

---

Has anyone had any success adding PNGs to PDFkit via the browser, and if so what method did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution as per this https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/image.coffee just make sure your name your png files with at capital ending .PNG, it worked for me.

Comment: This makes me very sad

Comment: I was very sad when I read this and thought they had actually put that check in for some reason, but this wasn't actually it.  It is checking data.toString('ascii', 1, 4) is 'PNG' where data is actually the file contents and it is checking for the string PNG in the header which is actually correct.