# Node.js PNG buffer getting Unknown Image Format Error

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, bwip-js

I'm using [bwip-js](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js) to generate barcodes and [pdfkit](https://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html) to generate a pdf that will display said barcode.

I'm having bwip-js generate png images of the barcodes, however it only provides a buffer of the png. I'm then using fs.writeFile to produce a png from that buffer (may be doing this part wrong).

Anyway, when I get to put the png in the pdf, pdfkit gives an error that the image is an `Uknown image format`

Meanwhile, if I open the directory in which the png was saved in my computer's file explorer, I can open the image just fine.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450943/pdfkit-unknown-image-format-error-for-png) answer seemingly describing the same issue, but I had no luck having bwip-js generate the png using .PNG instead of .png

I feel as though I'm missing something here with taking the buffer that bwip-js provides and converting it into a png file.

Code:

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const bwipjs = require("bwip-js");
const fs = require("fs");

function generateCustomerInvoice(data) {
  const id = "12345678"
  bwipjs
    .toBuffer({
      bcid: "code128",
      text: id,
      scale: 3,
      height: 10,
      includetext: true,
      textxalign: "center",
    })
    .then((png) => {
      fs.writeFile("./barcodes/" + id + ".png", png, () => {});
      console.log("Barcode Finished");
    })
    .then(() => {
      const doc = new PDFDocument({ autoFirstPage: false });
      doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./pdfs/customer/" + id + ".pdf"));
      doc.addPage({ size: "A5", margin: 20 });
      doc.lineWidth(1);
      doc.lineCap("butt").moveTo(20, 20).lineTo(399.53, 20).stroke();
      doc.lineCap("butt").moveTo(20, 20).lineTo(20, 575.28).stroke();
      doc.lineCap("butt").moveTo(399.53, 20).lineTo(399.53, 575.28).stroke();
      doc.lineCap("butt").moveTo(20, 575.28).lineTo(399.53, 575.28).stroke();
      doc.fontSize(12).text("Customer Invoice", 40, 40);
      doc.image("./barcodes/" + id + ".png", 40, 40);
      doc.end();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your write ".png" image part is wrong.

Node.js operates on a non-blocking I/O model, it means it doesn't wait for operations like reading from or writing to the filesystem to complete before moving on to the next line of code. This is great for performance but can lead to issues when one operation depends on the completion of another.

In your function, you're using fs.writeFile() to write the barcode image to disk. This method is asynchronous – it starts the writing process and then immediately moves on, not waiting for the file write to complete.

The fs.writeFile() function is asynchronous.

This means it starts the file-writing process and then immediately moves on to the next line of code without waiting for the file-writing to complete.

So next step "fs.createWriteStream()" no chance to reading finished image.
So this code will create the correct PDF file.

```js
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const bwipjs = require("bwip-js");
const fs = require("fs");

function generateCustomerInvoice(invoiceData) {
    const id = invoiceData.invoiceNumber;
    const barcodeDir = "./barcodes/";
    const pdfDir = "./pdfs/customer/";

    if (!fs.existsSync(barcodeDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(barcodeDir, { recursive: true });
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(pdfDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(pdfDir, { recursive: true });
    }

    bwipjs.toBuffer({
        bcid: "code128",
        text: id,
        scale: 3,
        height: 10,
        includetext: true,
        textxalign: "center",
    })
        .then((png) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.writeFile("./barcodes/" + id + ".png", png, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error("Error writing file:", err);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Barcode Finished");
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            const doc = new PDFDocument({ autoFirstPage: false });
            doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./pdfs/customer/" + id + ".pdf"));
            doc.addPage({ size: "A5", margin: 20 });

            doc.fontSize(12).text("Customer Invoice", 40, 30);

            doc.image("./barcodes/" + id + ".png", 40, 60, { width: 150 });

            doc.fontSize(10).text(`Customer Name: ${invoiceData.customerName}`, 40, 130);

            const tableTop = 160;
            doc.fontSize(10);
            doc.text("Description", 40, tableTop);
            doc.text("Quantity", 200, tableTop);
            doc.text("Price", 280, tableTop);
            doc.text("Total", 360, tableTop);

            let verticalPosition = tableTop;
            invoiceData.items.forEach(item => {
                verticalPosition += 20;
                doc.text(item.description, 40, verticalPosition);
                doc.text(item.quantity, 200, verticalPosition);
                doc.text(`$${item.price.toFixed(2)}`, 280, verticalPosition);
                doc.text(`$${(item.quantity * item.price).toFixed(2)}`, 360, verticalPosition);
            });

            doc.end();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error in PDF generation: ", err);
        });
}

generateCustomerInvoice({
    customerName: "Tom Cruise",
    invoiceNumber: "INV-10001",
    items: [
        { description: "Item 1", quantity: 2, price: 100.00 },
        { description: "Item 2", quantity: 5, price: 50.00 }
    ],
});
```

Result
[image]

More detail in [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-promises-in-javascript/)

Comment: Beautiful! Appreciate the explanation. I had a feeling it had something to do with that but apparently was erroneously thinking that when the console.log("Barcode Finished") fired that the barcode was finished - clearly not. Also thanks for the table example for pdfkit - was still working on playing around with formatting in pdfkit.

Comment: No problem, Thanks for your accepting, can you give me upvote too?
You can click up arrow from my answer. it will make me happy!